# is it possible to write database code with java to work with all databases

Tags: java, sql

I have a question which probably have been asked a million times, but I am at the point where I need to determine something like this.
Here is the question:
Is there some way to write Java code that queries, updates, inserts,deletes, calls stored procs etc using one type of code regardless of the fact which database there might be behind the scene?
Such as I write code put it on a system and it automatically detects that db is MS SQL Server and works, then in another case database may be Oracle but application doesnt need any code changes and automatically detects and works and so on so forth....

If this is not possible then what is the best approach to almost get to this level of abstraction...e.g
Have a config file and only make changes in that file regard which db drive will be used ?

Thanks

Comment: There are some queries that differ between databases. If you use those queries, the answer is no.

Comment: My personal opinion, but why you want to have this level of abstraction? In real scenario it's very rare case to change DB from one provider to another

Comment: The short answer is no, not all databases use the exact same syntax.

Comment: http://www.hibernate.org/?

Comment: Sorry, this is a conversation question and does not fit the StackOverflow format [FAQ]

Comment: Are you trying to solve a problem you have or one you imagine you might one day?

Answer (score 1):

I have recently been a convert to using QueryDSL: http://www.querydsl.com/

Using this to construct your queries, all you need to do is provide the proper "template" when you declare your query object and it provides the mapping for that particular database platform.  I have not went as far as using it to call stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Go for [HQL(Hibernate query language)](http://www.hibernate.org/) which is object oriented. For this you need to use hibernate. This way you dont have to depend on syntax of particular db. In case you want to switch from one db to another, it will be smooth